# Select Item In List Using Tag and Value

Tags: javascript, applescript, applescript-objc

I can't quite get my Javascript to select this item in a list. There are two identifiers that I must use to select an item in a list, using Javascript in an Applescript. I can't feasibly script the GUI, so this must be done programatically. Below is my latest effort.

**HTML Tag and Value:**

```
<option value="48">48&nbsp;-&nbsp;State</option>
```

**Javascript attempt:**

```
do JavaScript "var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  if(elements[i].value == '48') {
    elements[i].checked = true;
  }
}" in doc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selected is the attribute for option.

```
elements[i].selected = true;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JU63h/6/